# How to UPDATE item only if cached value is not older than the current one

Tags: java, postgresql, caching

I have a generic java multi-user client server CRUD system where each user gets all items via `SELECT`, adds new items via `INSERT`, removes existing items via `DELETE` and modifies existing items via `UPDATE`.

All tables contain `date_last_modified TIMESTAMPTZ` and `user_last_modified INTEGER REFERENCES users(id)` columns.

I want to prevent a situation when at first each user `SELECT`s all items and then several users modify similar item and each subsequent UPDATE overwrites previous data.

I am trying to create an `UPDATE` query that compares `date_last_modified` value on client and on server and abort query if values are not equal (meaning someone had already modified it).

If another approach exists to handle a situation when a cached item is older then the one in DB then you are welcome.

Comment: Check into locking and transactions.

Comment: @shawnt00 I know about transactions and use them when modifying several related tables at once.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your approach is good but maybe you can implement it using a trigger before update

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is ok but you can avoid aborting query (and also avoid querying timestamp beforehand in transaction for comparing the values) by adding `date_last_modified` to

```sql
UPDATE ... WHERE ... AND date_last_modified = ?
```

If the timestamp does not match no rows are updated.

`Statement.executeUpdate(...)` returns the number of updated rows. If it is 0 you can notify user about the race condition (and rollback transaction if needed).

You can also add a column `serial update_count` for this purpose. However, `timestampz` is ok if the value is changed on every update.